# Do Entities support INotifyPropertyChanged events?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a DataGrid, bound to a CollectionViewSource, whose source in an DBSet.Local (an ObservableCollection).

I have found that if I execute a context.entry(c).Reload or change the value of a property in an Entity directly (not through the DataGrid), **the updated values are not reflected in the DataGrid unless I CollectionViewSource.Refresh().**

This seems odd. Changes that I make in the DataGrid make it to the Entity by the time I context.SaveChanges. But, changes made directly to the entity, after the initial loading into the DBSet, are not reflected to the DataGrid unless I refresh the CollectionViewSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBContext, the recent version of entity framework does not natively support INotifyPropertyChanged, since they are plain old clr objects (POCOs)

You will have to cook this in yourself by editing the T4 templates, or using something like PostSharp to implement it with attributes.

Finally, you can simply revert to the old ObjectContext, but this isn't recommended.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862085/474702