# C# Convert All Dependency Properties to INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 20 C# classes with a lot of properties that defined as Dependency Properties.

I need a fast way to convert all of these properties into INotifyPropertyChanged properties.

convert these properties would be the following 3 tasks:

1. Delete the all the Dependency Property related code for each property and replace it with simple property implementation.
2. Add to the relative interface an inheritance to INotifyPropertyChanged.
3. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the related class.

I am looking for a something like script or code that will do that.
Even only the first of the 3 tasks will be fine because its most of the work.

thank you in advance.

Comment: T4 Templates. Try searching.

Comment: http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/blog-series-model-driven-development-with-t4-templates-part-3.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861917/ef6-poco-inotifypropertychanged-without-viewmodels, and so on. If it's a one-time operation, some RegEx find&replace will also do the trick.

Comment: thank you ,from now on we will probably will use T4 Templates,

Comment: Have a look at [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody)